# Count and organize wrt time data with impala

Tags: sql, impala, amazon-athena

I have a panel that looks like this:
Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 ...   Time
...
And for every category I have such a panel with the variables and the time.
I want to count all the variables for a given category and given point in time. In Athena the following code works but not in impala:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, month, day, year
from data_source
where category = ‘type1’
group by(month, day, year) 
order by month, day

SELECT COUNT(*) as total, month, day, year
    from data_source
    where category = ‘type2’
    group by(month, day, year) 
    order by month, day
```

etc...

But it aint work in Impala

Comment: Can you define "ain't work". like e.g. what Errors/Exceptions did you get if any, or what unexpected result or behavior did you get as opposed to what you had expected exactly etc.?

Comment: can you wrap keyword columns with backquote `  - ` month`, ` day`, ` year` and try again?